# Detectar pulsación de un botón dentro del Navigation Drawer en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

He añadido un botón al navigation Drawer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**nav_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/app_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="@string/nav_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_title"
            android:text="@string/nav_summary" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_local_profile"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:tint="#FFF"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_local_black_24dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

en **MainActivity.java** lo asigno y lanzo un listener para su pulsación.

```
ImageButton myLocalProfile = findViewById(R.id.btn_local_profile);
if (myLocalProfile != null) {
    myLocalProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick Image button: ");

        }
    });
}
```

El problema es que no detecta la pulsación del botón, es decir que `myLocalProfile` es nulo.

Comment: Has probado a hacer: ImageButton myLocalProfile = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_local_profile); myLocalProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick Image button: ");

        }
    });

Comment: No es normal que ni siquiera te entre al método

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano por lo visto los controles dentro del navigation pertenecen a la vista navigationview

Comment: "myLocalProfile es null", no estas inflando nav_header.xml dentro de tu NavigationView : navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header); ?

Comment: @Webserveis busca el ImageButton dentro de la instancia del navigationView : ImageButton myLocalProfile = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.btn_local_profile);

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de encontrar una solución, no ser si es apropiada

Mirando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220041/how-to-intent-image-button-in-navigation-drawer-header) he encontrado

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)navigationView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
       //DO YOUR CODE
    }
 });
```

Que se debe hacer referencia a la vista del menú lateral, pero tampoco me ha funcionado, me puesto a mirar mas y e encontrado `getHeaderView`

Me funciona con:

`ImageButton myLocalProfile = navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.btn_local_profile);`

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tu código veo que inflas un header (`nav_header.xml`) dentro de tu  `NavigationView`, seguramente de esta forma:

```
navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
```

si esta vista se cargo dentro del `NavigationView` y esta vista contiene tu `ImageButton`, entonces puedes sin problema encontrar la referencia y asignar un `onClickListener`:

```
   navigationView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //Click Imagebutton.
            }
        });
```

---

**Actualización**:

Encontré el problema, estas obteniendo una referencia del `ImageButton`, pero esta debe buscarse dentro del `NavigationView`, esto para que no tenga valor null y de esta forma poder asignar un listener:

```
//ImageButton myLocalProfile = findViewById(R.id.btn_local_profile);

ImageButton myLocalProfile = navigationView.findViewById(R.id.btn_local_profile);

if (myLocalProfile != null) {
    myLocalProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick Image button: ");

        }
    });
}
```